# Unable to send email with IIS7

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, email, iis, smtp

I'm migrating a website from IIS6 to IIS7.  I have everything working but the site will not send emails.

I have confirmed that the server is handling emails correctly, because when I drop a text document into the pickup folder it is delivered, but when I try to send a message via code I either get an error or just nothing.

The SMTP virtual server is setup with standard settings.
The website in question is using 4.0 Framework, Integrated Application pool, I've tried both the ApplicationPoolIdentity, and the NetworkService with no effect.  For the site's SMTP module I've tried an SMTP server of 127.0.0.1, localhost and the server's domain name, all on port 25.

For testing I've been using VBS and classic asp to send an email as well as asp.net.

I've been trying very basic scripts copied off the internet where all the comments say that it works.  For example

vb.net.  This code shows no error, but no message is sent and I've found nothing in the event viewer

```
Public Shared errorEmailTo As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("errorEmailTo")
Public Shared errorEmailFrom As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("errorEmailFrom")

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim email As String = "This is a test email."
    show.Text = "To: " + System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("errorEmailTo") + "<br/>"
    show.Text += "From: " + System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("errorEmailFrom") + "<br/>"
    Try
        Helper.SendError(email)
        show.Text += "No Error"
    Catch ex As Exception
        show.Text += "Error: " + ex.Message
    End Try

End Sub

Public Shared Sub SendError(ByVal strBody As String)

    Dim Email As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(errorEmailFrom, errorEmailTo)
    Email.Subject = "Error Message"
    Email.Body = strBody
    Dim mailClient As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient()
    mailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = True
    mailClient.EnableSsl = False


    Try
        mailClient.Send(Email)
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
```

VBS.  This code returns the error "The transport failed to connect to the server."  For which I've not found anything other than a new nearly identical code block

```
strSMTPFrom = "donotreply@here.com"
strSMTPTo = "me@here.com"
strSMTPRelay = "localhost"
strTextBody = "Body of your email"
strSubject = "Subject line"


Set oMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
oMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 
oMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = strSMTPRelay
oMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25 
oMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update

oMessage.Subject = strSubject
oMessage.From = strSMTPFrom
oMessage.To = strSMTPTo
oMessage.TextBody = strTextBody

oMessage.Send
```

Classic ASP gives the same error message.

```
<%
Dim sch, cdoConfig, cdoMessage
sch = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/"
Set cdoConfig = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
With cdoConfig.Fields
    .Item(sch & "sendusing") = 2 ' cdoSendUsingPort
    .Item(sch & "smtpserver") = "localhost"
    .Item(sch & "smtpserverport") = 25
    .update
End With
Set cdoMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
With cdoMessage
    Set .Configuration = cdoConfig
    .From = "donotreply@here.com"
    .To = "me@here.com"
    .Subject = "Email test"
    .TextBody = "This is the test body of the email"
    .Send
End With
Set cdoMessage = Nothing
Set cdoConfig = Nothing
%>
```

I've found example after example that give these code blocks as working examples, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try pointing the address at an actual SMTP server. Or set the correct [delivery method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.deliverymethod(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: All i knew of sending email's need to have mailer_email_add and password.

Comment: Email isn't magic. It has to go somewhere. Ask your network admin where your SMTP sever is.

Comment: OP said, `For the site's SMTP module I've tried an SMTP server of 127.0.0.1, localhost and the server's domain name, all on port 25.` No...that needs to point to a real mail server, e.g. `mail.gmail.com`. The IIS SMTP feature is a relay agent only. It will not send email directly to any recipient. It can only relay mail to a real mail server that will actually send the mail out to the recipient.

Comment: @MrGadget, Thank you for the clarification about the native SMTP.  How would I make use of the relay?  The old server for this site also used the local SMTP, there is nothing referencing outside services.

Comment: Either way, you're going to need to find out where your mail server is. Are you running an email server locally, or are you planning to use hosted solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brought in a fresh pair of eyes, and we found the answer.

The virtual SMTP server was listening on port 465(SSL), not 25.  So with that corrected, classic ASP and VBS worked, but not VB.Net.  We created a new Virtual SMTP server, listening on port 587.  And as long as VB.Net had SSL disabled it would work.  It appears that the new server didn't receive the SSL certificate during migration.